# Get 'id' value from vue-router's link

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

How to get an object value from vue-router's link? 
For example 'id' in this link
http://laravel.dev/#!/messages/**1703**

So with that id i can fetch specific data from database.

My code

```
var detailMessage = Vue.extend({
template: '#detailMessage',
data: function() {
    return {
        id: ''
    }
},
ready: function(id) {
    this.getID(id);
},
methods: {
    getID: function(id) {
    this.$http.get('/api/messages/' + id, function(data) {
        alert(data);
            })
        }
    }
})


var router = new VueRouter()
router.map({
'/api/messages/:idMessage': {
    name: 'sentMessage',
    component: detailMessage
    }
})
```

Sorry, the error was when link clicked, view and url change but what send to server is
http://laravel.dev/api/messages/undefined

Here error screenshot

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a "?" in this "question".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
router.map({
'/api/messages/:message_id': {
    name: 'sentMessage',
    component: detailMessage
    }
})
```

You can then access anywhere in the vm with `this.$route.params.message_id`

Comment: What if the route is being added by router.push?

Comment: Never mind, this site explains it clearly:  https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html